# Getting 73/115 testcases passed: Verifying an Alien dictionary

Tags: python, data-structures, testcase

Q. Given a sequence of words written in the alien language, and the order of the alphabet, return true if and only if the given words are sorted lexicographically in this alien language.
Following are some examples:

```
Input: words = ["hello","leetcode"], order = "hlabcdefgijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Output: true
Explanation: As 'h' comes before 'l' in this language, then the sequence is sorted.


Input: words = ["word","world","row"], order = "worldabcefghijkmnpqstuvxyz"
Output: false
Explanation: As 'd' comes after 'l' in this language, then words[0] > words[1], hence the sequence is unsorted.


Input: words = ["apple","app"], order = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Output: false
Explanation: The first three characters "app" match, and the second string is shorter (in size.
```

The following was my solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def isAlienSorted(self, words, order):
        orderDict = {}
        for index, char in enumerate(order):
            orderDict[char] = index

        for j in range(len(words)-1):
            for i in range(min(len(words[j]),len(words[j+1]))):
                word1 = words[j]
                word2 = words[j+1]
                if orderDict[word1[i]] == orderDict[word2[i]]:
                    continue
                if orderDict[word1[i]] > orderDict[word2[i]]:
                    return False
                if orderDict[word1[i]] < orderDict[word2[i]]:
                    return True
            if len(words[j]) > len(words[j+1]):
                return False

        return True
```

why are only 73/115 test cases being passed by this?

Comment: Is it Python 3 or Python 2? You’ve tagged both.

Comment: Anyway, `return True` is no good. You’ve only determined that `words[j]` and `words[j + 1]` are in the correct order at that point, not the rest of them. Instead, exit the loop with `break`, and figure out how to skip the length check. (Python even has a unique way to do that.)

Comment: Why are you using a class to do this?

Comment: @Ry- what is the unique way of exiting a loop in python?

Comment: Not of exiting the loop, but of skipping the length check when it was exited with `break`. [**`for…else`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: @Ry- your explanation of using break helped me find my answer. Please post it as an answer so i can upvote it

Comment: @boomselector: Why don’t you answer with exactly how you did it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Instead of returning true in the case where the order of the character of the preceding word is lesser than the order of the word after that word, you should skip that case, by using 'break'. This prevents the program from returning a false positive, since it might return 'true' even if there are other words ahead in the dictionary which are not in the correct order:

```
def isAlienSorted(self, words, order):
        orderDict = {}
        for index, char in enumerate(order):
            orderDict[char] = index

        for j in range(len(words)-1):
            word1 = words[j]
            word2 = words[j+1]
            for i in range(min(len(word1),len(word2))):
                if orderDict[word1[i]] != orderDict[word2[i]]:
                    if orderDict[word1[i]] > orderDict[word2[i]]:
                        return False
                    break
                elif len(word1) > len(word2):
                    return False

        return True
```

This solution was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Made few changes in your algorithm ,please check if this works

```
    def isAlienSorted(self, words, order):
        orderDict = {}
        for index, char in enumerate(order):
            orderDict[char] = index

        for j in range(len(words)-1):
            isCheck = True
            for i in range(min(len(words[j]),len(words[j+1]))):
                word1 = words[j]
                word2 = words[j+1]
                if orderDict[word1[i]] == orderDict[word2[i]]:
                    continue
                if orderDict[word1[i]] > orderDict[word2[i]]:
                    return False
                if orderDict[word1[i]] < orderDict[word2[i]]:
                    isCheck = False
                    break
            if isCheck and len(words[j]) > len(words[j+1]):
                return False

        return True
```